# How to spawn 'dummy clients' on the server-side which use the server's interface in Flask/Socketio

Tags: python, flask, socket.io

I have a Flask/SocketIO application which currently pairs two clients together to play a game together. Right now the clients are interacting with the server through some compiled client-side Javascript, and I am using socketio to define the sockets which the clients call, e.g., `movedForward` when that client moved forward. The client-side JS similarly defines websockets which the server will emit to, e.g., `partnerTurnedRight` when the server is passing the partner's movement to the other player.

I would like to create 'dummy' clients on the server side which can interact with a normal, remote client -- basically, a python implementation of the Javascript which is spawned every time a remote client connects. The idea is to have a server-side "player" play the game with a remote, human client.

I'm not sure how to go about implementing something like this. My intuition is that I should create a separate Flask/SocketIO app (somehow), which has sockets on for the messages the server sends (e.g., `partnerTurnedRight`) and emits messages the server expects (e.g., `movedForward`). Then, when a remote client connects, spawn a stateful subprocess which has its own unique sid and is able to interact with the server with the exact same interface as the remote client. However, I'm really not sure how to put everything together or how to actually spawn a server-side client like that.

An example project which does something like this, some pseudocode, or a general structure of how to set something like this up would be greatly appreciated!

(Part of the problem is that I don't know what search terms to use, so it's been hard finding examples.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [python-socketio](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#client-examples) package server-side using python. Here's an example of the client usage:

```
import socketio

sio = socketio.Client()

@sio.on('connect')
def on_connect():
    print('connected')
    sio.emit('Hello')

@sio.on('event')
def on_message(data):
    print('Received ', data)

@sio.on('disconnect')
def on_disconnect():
    print('disconnected')

sio.connect('http://localhost:5000')
sio.wait()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would need my client to be implemented in python. I found a few python packages/projects which seem to implement the client-side in python (e.g., https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio) -- I think this is the right direction?

Comment: Yes, if you must use python, that's a good option. I'll adjust my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! My client will be stateful, and I will spawn it (e.g., as a subprocess) when a remote client connects. So, to make it stateful, I'm assuming I can have either [1] some global variable(s) in this code which contain the state, or [2] wrap the event listeners in a class?

Comment: Absolutely @alsuhr

Comment: Yes thank you (using python-socketio to connect works, but I haven't gotten around to implementing the whole dummy client yet), I'll accept this answer.